# Select one value which is the max value of an another table where id is equal

Tags: mysql, sql

Select one value which is the max value of an another table where id is equal

```
SELECT colour 
FROM party_details WHERE (party_id) IN ( SELECT MAX('p_percentage') FROM colombo )
```

I have 2 Table Namely : party_details
                        colombo

I need to select the colour (column name :colour) from party_details where it is the maximum Value of the Colombo Table ( Column name: p_percentage )

Comment: Please provide sample data and desired results.  What is the maximum value, for instance?

Comment: Colombo Table
 party_id      p_percentage
      1                    31
      2                    45
      3                    15

party_details
party_id       colour
       1           Green
       2           Red
       3           Blue

Result should be : Red

Comment: See https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/333952/why-should-i-provide-a-minimal-reproducible-example-for-a-very-simple-sql-query and be advised that an Edit button is provided.

Answer (score 1):

Is this what you want?

```
select pd.color
from party_details pd
where pd.party_id = (select c.party_id
                     from colombo c
                     order by c.p_percentage desc
                     limit 1
                    );
```